# Docker Daemon not running possibly broken on my Arch system upon installing docker-desktop

Tags: docker-desktop, pacman, arch, docker-daemon

I had docker running perfectly on my Arch setup then one day I thought to install `docker-desktop` on my system as going through docs I downloaded install binary extracted the docker binary and tried to run docker engine again (all by mistake, as I had docker already installed). Then I moved to install `docker-desktop` on my system only to find that docker daemon is no longer running and I tried to uninstall docker and reinstall docker but upon running `sudo pacman -R docker` it gives -

```
\\checking dependencies...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: removing docker breaks dependency 'docker>=24.0.5' required by docker-desktop
```

Maybe I am missing something as it all happened few days ago and I was very busy in work to deal with it that time, I used windows system that was pre-configured with docker-desktop since, but I want to make it work back on my arch system.

I am not an expert in arch still learning, I need an expert to help me provide me some reference anything that may work, thanks.

Comment: Not an answer but why would you install Docker Desktop on Linux? If you just wanted a GUI, there are other tools that don't have the licensing issues

Comment: There is proper GUI from docker itself, that I have experience with using in my Windows set up with WSL, so I just went for it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this, it seems `docker-desktop` is installed on my `arch` system and it needs `docker` package (therefore it shows `dependencies conflict`), so I first removed `docker-desktop` (`sudo pacman -R docker-desktop`) then I was able to remove `docker` and it worked, now I can reinstall `docker` and configure it accordingly.